# SQLAlchemy custom load/save functionality (setter and getter)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using the SQLAlchemy ORM for loading/saving from the database. However, I would like specific functions to be called on loading the data from the database, something like this:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    _data = relationship('Data')

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []
        self.max_data = None
        self.min_data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, data):
        print('gone through setter')
        self.min_data = min(data)
        self.max_data = max(data)
        self._data = data
```

However, I noticed that the setters and getters aren't called when saving/loading from the db. Is there a way to have these setters and getters called?

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
# gone through setter
myclass.max_data
# 5
myclass.min_data
# 0
session.add(myclass)
session.commit()

del myclass

myclass = session.query(MyClass).all()[0]
# setter is not called here
myclass.max_data
# None
myclass.min_data
# None
```

I would like the setter to be called on loading from the db as well, so that the `min_data` and `max_data` are set (without having to save them in the db explicitly)

Comment: I am sure when you create an instance of `MyClass` class your `getter` and `setter` will work. Notice that you are getting and setting the instance attribute(`_data`) not the `_data` of relationship. So explain a bit what you want to return and set?

Comment: I added some detail to the end of my question

Comment: May you are missing the usage of setter and getter, so try this will show you setter work: `myclass.data = [1, 2, 3 4]`

Comment: Err sorry, I missed that line. I added it to the question. You are correct, this will call the setter.

However, I want the setter to also be called on the session.query(). When the MyClass table is accessed and loaded, I also want the min and max values to be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach behavior on load, use the [`load` event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load):

```
@event.listens_for(MyClass, "load")
def _set_min_max_on_load(target, context):
    target.max_data = max(target._data)
    target.min_data = min(target._data)
```

In this particular instance, it may be helpful to simply use `hybrid_property`s instead:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def max_data(self):
        return max(self.data)

    @max_data.expression
    def max_data(cls):
        return select([func.max(Data.__table__.c.some_value)]).where(Data.__table__.c.my_class_id == cls.id)
```